# Vault Kubernetes Authentication

Tags: kubernetes, vault

I have my own hosted Kubernetes cluster where I store my secrets in vault. To give my microservices access to the secrets managed by vault, I want to authenticate my microservices via their service accounts. The problem I'm facing is that vault rejects the service accounts (JWTs) with the following error:

```
apis/authentication.k8s.io/v1/tokenreviews: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

The service accounts are signed with Kubernetes own CA. I did not replace this with Vault's `pki` solution. Is it possible to configure Vault to trust my Kubernetes CA certificate and therefore the JWTs?

Comment: Hello Sebastian, what k8s version are you using? It appears that in 1.21 secret-based token format was changed and it can result in the error you encountered.

Comment: @PiotrMalec I'm using v1.21.7 indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of error can be caused by a recent change to [Service Account Issuer Discovery](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-service-account/#service-account-issuer-discovery) in Kubernetes 1.21.

In order to mitigate this issue, there are a couple of options that you can choose from based on your expectations:

1. Manually create a service account, secret and mount it in the pod as mentioned [on this github post](https://github.com/external-secrets/kubernetes-external-secrets/issues/721#issuecomment-979883828).
2. Disable issuer validation as mentioned [on another github post](https://github.com/external-secrets/kubernetes-external-secrets/issues/721#issue-868030068).
3. Downgrade the cluster to version 1.20.

There are also a couple of external blog articles about this on [banzaicloud.com](https://banzaicloud.com/blog/kubernetes-oidc/) and [particule.io](https://particule.io/en/blog/vault-1.21/).